# Renew letsencrypt certificate SSL - AMI Linux Amazon

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I trying to renew an SSL certificate on EC2 with AMI Linux Amazon but I am receiving the error below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx letsencrypt]$ ./letsencrypt-auto renew

Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /home/ec2-user/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in <module>
from certbot.main import main
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 12, in <module>
import zope.component
File "/home/ec2-user/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from zope.interface import Interface
ImportError: No module named interface
```

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Someone had the same problem as you](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/getting-error-couldnt-get-currently-installed-version-for-letsencrypt-when-trying-to-renew-my-certificates/27031), check the community forum from Let's Encrypt.

One solution from that thread was:

> Basically, I reinstalled it from scratch:
>
> ```
> cd $HOME/.local/share
> rm -fr letsencrypt
> unset PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT
> ./certbot-auto -d DOMAIN certonly --webroot -w DOCUMENT_ROOT --debug
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issues with an Amazon Linux instance that was originally set up with cert-bot and worked fine. I tried to fix some other issues by following another post and this is the result I came too

In the end, I had to do the following

```
rm -rf /opt/eff.org/*
```

It will probably fail on this one but setups a clean virtual environment

```
./certbot-auto --debug

cd /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python2.7

mv site-packages site-packages.sav

ln -s dist-packages/ site-packages
```

You're now ready to run `certbot-auto` again

```
./certbot-auto --debug
```